# Como mostrar um loading apenas no elemento no qual foi clicado

Tags: angular, typescript

Tenho a seguinte estrutura de repetição:

```
<div *ngFor="let notificacao of notificacoes; let i = index">
   {{notificacao.marketplace}}
   {{notificacao.data_entrada | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}} 
   {{notificacao.data_entrada | date:'shortTime'}}
   <h6><strong>{{notificacao.mensagem}}</strong>
      <i *ngIf="loading" class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin ml-2"></i>
      <svg *ngIf="!loading" (click)="testaLoadingExclusao(notificacao.identificador, i)">
      </svg>
   </h6>
</div>
```

minha função `testaLoadingExclusao()`

```
testaLoadingExclusao(identificador, index){
    this.loading = true;
}
```

Eu gostaria que aparecesse o loading apenas no elemento que eu cliquei, atualmente o icone de loading é mostrado em todos os itens da minha listagem quando eu clico no svg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faz assim no ts:

```
this.notificacoes= notificacoes.map(obj = > { obj.loading=false; return obj; });


testaLoadingExclusao(notificacao){
    notificacao.loading = true;
}
```

e no html

```
 <div *ngFor="let notificacao of notificacoes; let i = index">
       {{notificacao.marketplace}}
       {{notificacao.data_entrada | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}} 
       {{notificacao.data_entrada | date:'shortTime'}}
       <h6><strong>{{notificacao.mensagem}}</strong>
          <i *ngIf="notificacao.loading" class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin ml-2"></i>
          <svg *ngIf="!notificacao.loading" (click)="testaLoadingExclusao(notificacao)">
          </svg>
       </h6>
    </div>
```